# NodeJs Mysql - passing SQL Function(NOW()) with object

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database

so I'm trying to make a table row update with some data and date = NOW(), and it seems to be more annoying than I had thought. Here is what I tried and didn't work for some reason:

```
var sql_query_data = [{size:fileSize , loc:filename} , row_id];
con.query("UPDATE files SET ? AND date = NOW() WHERE id = ?" , sql_query_data , function ...)
```

And here's another one that didn't help (and I understand why):

```
var sql_query_data = [{size:fileSize , loc:filename, date:"NOW()"} , row_id];
con.query("UPDATE files SET ? WHERE id = ?" , sql_query_data , function...)
```

Does anyone have a good solution for me?

Comment: Your syntax is off.  Please describe in English terms what you are trying to update, which columns, with what data, and what restrictions.

Comment: I'm just trying to update a column called "date" with now(), along with some other columns. The problem is that the Now() function doesn't work in the ways shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for doing an update with MySQL is:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col1 = <some_val>,
    col2 = <some_other_val>,
    ...
WHERE condition = ?
```

In Node.js, your query might look something like this:

```
con.query(
    'UPDATE files SET col1 = ?, date = NOW() WHERE id = ?',
    [var1, some_id], 
    function (err, results) {

    }
);
```

Here the variables `var1` is the value to which you are updating `col1`, and `some_id` will fill the placeholder in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Oh, that was my mistake! I used "ADD" instead of a comma. Thank you